# Determine if an sql query modifies the database

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, regex

I have a list of strings that contain valid `SQL` expressions.
I need to execute only those that do not modify the database.
What would be the best way to do this? Just doing something like:

```
if(sqlQuery.contains("DELETE")){  
  //don't execute this
}
```

seems like a bad hack

**Update:**
I'll make this more specific.
I already have a list of `SQL` queries that are allowed. I want to make sure only these are executed.
What would be the best way to match against these?

Comment: which RDBMS engine are you using?

Comment: Where do the `SQL` expressions come from?  Are they user generated?  The best way to be absolutely sure is to create a new login to the database that has no permissions to modify anything, and run all the SQL scripts under that user login.

Comment: @mellamokb:Yes they are user generated

Comment: I don't think there is a 100% way of doing that.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  If you are building a website, for example, where users can test queries, just create a login with only SELECT access.  For example, sqlfiddle.com allows user-generated queries, and the author's source code is publicly available: https://github.com/jakefeasel/sqlfiddle.  He uses permissions to control what you can run, isolates new table setups in completely separate databases, and executes all test queries in a transaction that is immediately rolled back at the end.

Comment: when you say modify.. do you want to supress DDL / DML ?

Comment: As @mellamokb suggests, you will ***fail*** to protect your database in this way.  Simply ensure that all queries are executed under a login that doesn't have permission to do these actions.  Why re-invent the wheel?  Just learn how use the user permissions system that exists in your RDBMS.

Comment: What if I only accept `SELECT`?

Comment: What do you mean *accept*?  You mean you will make sure the string `SELECT` is at the beginning of the query?  That's easily broken as well (for example: `SELECT 1;DROP TABLE ABC;`).  If you mean to lock down the SQL user to only have permissions to `SELECT`, then yes, that should work.

Comment: @mellamokb:But are these types of sql queries `sql1;sql2` allowed by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest and best (most comprehensive) way to do this is to create a read-only user and only connect to the database with that user.  In SQLServer, the easiest way to do this is to create the user and add them to the built-in **"db_datareader"** role.  This will only allow SELECTs.

And you have to worry about more than just DELETEs, INSERTs or UPDATEs.  You also have to be careful about calling any stored procedures, so to be safe you'd also want to remove execute rights, ALTER rights, GRANT rights, etc...

EDIT:
Just execute this...

```
CREATE LOGIN [user] WITH PASSWORD='password', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[your_db], CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
CREATE USER [user] FOR LOGIN [user]
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'your_db'
GO
```

Comment: @Jim: Are you even reading the answers given to you?  This answer *explains* how to only "accept" SELECT...

Comment: @mellamokb:The way I understand this it will *effectivelly* allow `SELECT`.

Comment: +1 this is the correct approach, via security. Parsing SQL will lead to nowhere!

Comment: @Jim: What's the difference?  The reason you want to *effectively* allow `SELECT` is to avoid malicious attempts to damage your database.  As long as you use string parsing, you leave the window open for clever users to damage your database.  But if you use permissions, every possible valid, honest `SELECT` query you can invent should be allowed, while tricky attempts to sneak in updates or damages to database through the `SELECT` query will be entirely prevented.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I fully understand creating read-only users, but there are valid applications for parsing SQL to determine if it is read only or not. Content switching for a load balanced server is one example, where all "update" scripts are sent to the master DB while "read" scripts are sent to the slave.  There are multiple reasons as to why one might need to parse SQL and throwing out the "create a read only user" answer might not be applicable.

Answer (score 2):

`DELETE` is not the only SQL instruction that might modify your database; `INSERT` will definitely do so, and `UPDATE` might (depending on your exact query). So just analysing the Strings might be a hard way of doing this.

As long as performance is not really an issue, you could start a transaction, run your instructions one by one, check the number of affected rows for each of them, and finally rollback your transaction. Afterwards, you only run those statements that affected 0 rows.

Besides, check your database documentation: some RDBMS-es (like Oracle) don't support rollback of DDL statements like `ALTER TABLE`, `DROP TABLE` and the like...

Comment: Don't forget `MERGE`, `DROP TABLE` and a lot of other statements.

Comment: Depending on the exact query, an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` *might* leave your database unchanged (for example, if no rows match the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Jim - [SELECT INTO](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) would not be read only.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a bulletproof way of preventing the alteration of records by simply checking the content of the given SQL. For example, you might have a field, which has the value "update" and some user is trying to query all rows which contain this value, yet the SQL would not be executed, since it contains a "blacklisted" string.
I guess the only safe way would be to execute the SQL's with an user, who has no rights to alter records at all.